# how to close android keypad popup for edittext but i need keypad below edittext

Tags: android, android-widget, keyboard

I need keypad for `EditText` its overlaps my `EditText` but i need keypad below the `EditText` view.

```
    EDIT:
    finally i got the answer for this. we need to set 
      android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" in `edittext`
```

it hides the popup.

Comment: whats your exact issue/requirement ?

Comment: @iDroid Explorer - while i click on the edittext it will close my edittext,but i need only keypad below the edit text, it will not close my edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `android:windowSoftInputMode` or `android:windowSoftInputMode` to to make room for the soft keyboard without hiding EditText

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

or

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398102/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-doesnt-make-any-difference

Comment: i have search edittext box so while clicking one letter it will shorlist the list view below so i need keypad only half of the page only....

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N : i think i'm not getting you can u explain it more

Comment: `edittext` will not hide while i am clicking keypad i will attach image in my blog http://enpboss.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is set this parameter `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your `AndroidManifest` for your `Activity` class.

Comment: do u have any examples for pls send me!!

Comment: Oh i'm absolutelly forgot one thing - if your `EditText` located in `ScrollView` this wouldn't help, and unfortunately i don't know how to handle it in this situation. Your `EditText` is in `ScrollView`?