# windowSoftInputMode set to stateHidden|adjustResize not working in Android

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/background_grey"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/logo_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_container" >

        <!-- some layout components-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo_layout"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin" >

                    <!-- some layout components-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activation_code_entry_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activation_body_second_paragraph"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/enter_passcode_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <!-- some layout components-->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/activationCode"
                style="@style/FormField"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:hint="@string/activation_enter_code"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"/>

                        <!-- some layout components-->
        </RelativeLayout>

                    <!-- some layout components-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and in the Application Manifest file I am setting the activity as

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

but the view do not scroll up when soft keyboard appears.

Comment: this was the only solution working for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30019136/832008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue. Here it is.

I modified the first child of main scroll view in the following way

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
```

i.e. I added

```
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

this made the layout always show the bottom as the gravity was bottom.

I hope this helps others

Cheers

Comment: Pretty much what I needed. I set mine to `fill` though

Answer (score 5):

It wont be resized if you use theme with no title bar. 
Maybe this question can help you: 
[Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)