# windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working with translucent action/navbar

Tags: android, resize, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat, window-soft-input-mode

I have problems with the translucent actionbar/navbar in the new *Android KitKat* (4.4) and the `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

Normaly, changing the *InputMode* to `adjustResize`, the app should resize itself when keyboard is shown, but here it won't! If I delete the lines for the transparent effect, the resize is working.

So if the keyboard is visible, my `ListView` is under it and I can't access the last few items (only by hiding the keyboard manually).

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XYZ"
android:versionCode="23"
android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.XYZStyle" >
    <activity
        android:name="XYZ"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

values-v19/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme.XYZStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigationbar__height" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" doesn't make any difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398102/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-doesnt-make-any-difference)

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You are missing the following property:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the root `RelativeLayout` of the **fragment** .xml layout.

**Update:**

Last year there was an interesting talk by Chris Bane that explains in good detail how this works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE

Comment: This code working when you are use full screen flag in your activity    Thank you

Answer (score 38):

There's a related bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63777). I've found a workaround that, from limited testing, seems to do the trick with no repercussions. Add a custom implementation of your root `ViewGroup` (I almost always am using `FrameLayout`, so this is what I've tested with) with the logic below. Then, use this custom layout in place of your root layout, and ensure you set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. You can then just call `getInsets()` any time after layout (e.g. add an `OnPreDrawListener`) to adjust the rest of your layout to account for the system insets, if desired.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

/**
 * @author Kevin
 *         Date Created: 3/7/14
 *
 * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63777
 * 
 * When using a translucent status bar on API 19+, the window will not
 * resize to make room for input methods (i.e.
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE} and
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN} are
 * ignored).
 * 
 * To work around this; override {@link #fitSystemWindows(android.graphics.Rect)},
 * capture and override the system insets, and then call through to FrameLayout's
 * implementation.
 * 
 * For reasons yet unknown, modifying the bottom inset causes this workaround to
 * fail. Modifying the top, left, and right insets works as expected.
 */
public final class CustomInsetsFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private int[] mInsets = new int[4];

    public CustomInsetsFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public final int[] getInsets() {
        return mInsets;
    }

    @Override
    protected final boolean fitSystemWindows(@NotNull Rect insets) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // Intentionally do not modify the bottom inset. For some reason, 
            // if the bottom inset is modified, window resizing stops working.
            // TODO: Figure out why.

            mInsets[0] = insets.left;
            mInsets[1] = insets.top;
            mInsets[2] = insets.right;

            insets.left = 0;
            insets.top = 0;
            insets.right = 0;
        }

        return super.fitSystemWindows(insets);
    }
}
```

Since `fitSystemWindow`s was deprecated, please refer to the answer below to complete the workaround.

Comment: Actually SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN seems to be NOT ignored according to my experience - it will move whole screen up, including system bar and shift keyboard under focused view.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct about the SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN. I used this in my fragment:         getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: That was the only way I could achieve having adjustResize for activity (needed for the scrolling of the view upon showing keyboard), fitSystemWindows set as true so that the scroll actually happens on >= Lollipop and having translucent statusBar. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 30):

@kcoppock answer is really helpful, but fitSystemWindows was deprecated in API level 20

So since API 20 (KITKAT_WATCH) you should override onApplyWindowInsets

```
@Override
public final WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        return super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(0, 0, 0,
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom()));
    } else {
        return insets;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see difference between your solution and @kcoppock answer. Tested both. When I use your method the same todo items 1 - 5 including fitSystemWindows of kcoppock answer must be used. When I omit fitSystemWindows status bar is translucent but windowSoftInputMode=“adjustResize” is not working (I do not see input in which im writing)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to customize the insets and you are targeting API level >=21 you can accomplish this without having to create a custom view group. By just setting `fitsSystemWindows` padding will be applied to your container view by default, which you may not want.

The version checks are built into this method and only devices >= 21 will execute the code inside the lambda. Kotlin example:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(container) { view, insets ->
  insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(0, 0, 0, insets.systemWindowInsetBottom).apply {
    ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, this)
  }
}
```

Make sure your layout still sets the `fitsSystemWindows` flag otherwise the window insets listener will not be called.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />
```

These sources are helpful:

https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec
https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9

Comment: This still remains the best approach, since you can apply this is your `BaseFragment`, along with `view.fitsSystemWindows = true` and it just works without any changes to the actual XML layouts or View subclasses.

Comment: Wanted to note that the solution may not work for some view acting as `container` (in my case it was `ConstraintLayout`). The fix was to wrap my layout with `FrameLayout` that became a new `container`. Appreciate the solution!

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me to have translucent status bar and adjustResize in fragment:

1. Make a custom RelativeLayout as @Victor91 and @kcoppock said.
2. Use CustomRelativeLayout as parent layout for your fragment.
3. Declare theme with android:windowTranslucentStatus = true
4. The container Activity must be declared in Manifest with
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and use the declared
   theme
5. **Please Use fitsSystemWindows on fragment root layout!**

   ```
   public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

       private int[] mInsets = new int[4];

       public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       }

       public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
       }

       @Override
       public final WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
               mInsets[0] = insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft();
               mInsets[1] = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
               mInsets[2] = insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight();
               return super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(0, 0, 0,
                       insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom()));
           } else {
               return insets;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Then in xml,

```
<com.blah.blah.CustomRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
</com.blah.blah.CustomRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, and I'm looking for solution some time now. It's working perfectly, but you have to add some extra padding to your toolbar, without it your toolbar will be overlapping statusbar

Answer (score 10):

A small update on the helpful *@Victor Rendina*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526076/3290339) caused by the `replaceSystemWindowInsets` and `systemWindowInsetBottom` methods deprecation.

**Prerequisites:**

- *API* >= 21
- `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha02'` at least

**Kotlin extension:**

```
fun View?.fitSystemWindowsAndAdjustResize() = this?.let { view ->
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
        view.fitsSystemWindows = true
        val bottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom

        WindowInsetsCompat
            .Builder()
            .setInsets(
                WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars(),
                Insets.of(0, 0, 0, bottom)
            )
            .build()
            .apply {
                ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, this)
            }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
rootView.fitSystemWindowsAndAdjustResize()
```

where `rootView` is literally the root view of the layout :)

**Note:** *if the extension does not work for your root view (I ran into this when having `ConstraintLayout` as the `rootView`) wrap the entire layout with a `FrameLayout` so that the `FrameLayout` becomes the new root view*.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem,
My Activity had a ScrollView as root view and with translucent statusbar activated it didn't resize correctly when keyboard showed... and conseguently the screen didn't scrolled hiding the input views.

Solution:
Moved everything (layout and activity logic) inside a new Fragment.
Then changed the Activity to only include this Fragment. Now everything works as expected!

This is the layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this first at your root layout.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

When you use this approach, it becomes your responsibility to ensure that critical parts of your app's UI (for example, the built-in controls in a Maps application) don't end up getting covered by system bars. This could make your app unusable. In most cases you can handle this by adding the android:fitsSystemWindows attribute to your XML layout file, set to true. This adjusts the padding of the parent ViewGroup to leave space for the system windows. This is sufficient for most applications.

In some cases, however, you may need to modify the default padding to get the desired layout for your app. To directly manipulate how your content lays out relative to the system bars (which occupy a space known as the window's "content insets"), override fitSystemWindows(Rect insets). The fitSystemWindows() method is called by the view hierarchy when the content insets for a window have changed, to allow the window to adjust its content accordingly. By overriding this method you can handle the insets (and hence your app's layout) however you want.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#behind

If you want to become a master window fitter, please watch the video from the android developer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE

Answer (score 3):

Based on Joseph Johnson's workaround in [Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)

call this in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()` in your activity.

`AndroidBug5497Workaround.assistActivity(this);`

a litte different from original replace `return (r.bottom - r.top);` with `return r.bottom;` in `computeUsableHeight()`

for some reason, i must set my activity `fitsSystemWindows` attribute to `false`.

this workaround saved me. it's works well for me. hope can help you.

the implementation class is:

```
public class AndroidBug5497Workaround {

// For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
// To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

public static void assistActivity (Activity activity) {
    new AndroidBug5497Workaround(activity);
}

private View mChildOfContent;
private int usableHeightPrevious;
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

private AndroidBug5497Workaround(Activity activity) {
    FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
    mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
        }
    });
    frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
}

private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent() {
    int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
    if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
        int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
        int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
        if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4)) {
            // keyboard probably just became visible
            frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;
        } else {
            // keyboard probably just became hidden
            frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
        }
        mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
        usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
    }
}

private int computeUsableHeight() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    return r.bottom;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't work with the translucent status bar; that setting forces the window into fullscreen mode which does not work with adjustResize.

You can either use adjustPan or use the fitsSystemWindows properties. I would suggest reading about the feature though, it has significant side effects:

https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Answer (score 1):

I had like a problem.

I set windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds to 'true' and my app should show under status bar.

It's my activity theme.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="KITKAT">false</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and I got help from [jianshu's blog](http://www.jianshu.com/p/4f744c95a51c/comments/5001614).
you can read code but text like me.
I add few code more.

```
public final class ZeroInsetsFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private int[] mInsets = new int[4];

    public ZeroInsetsFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ZeroInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZeroInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public final int[] getInsets() {
        return mInsets;
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsets computeSystemWindowInsets(WindowInsets in, Rect outLocalInsets) {
        outLocalInsets.left = 0;
        outLocalInsets.top = 0;
        outLocalInsets.right = 0;

        return super.computeSystemWindowInsets(in, outLocalInsets);
    }

    @Override
    protected final boolean fitSystemWindows(@NonNull Rect insets) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // Intentionally do not modify the bottom inset. For some reason,
            // if the bottom inset is modified, window resizing stops working.
            // TODO: Figure out why.

            mInsets[0] = insets.left;
            mInsets[1] = insets.top;
            mInsets[2] = insets.right;

            insets.left = 0;
            insets.top = 0;
            insets.right = 0;
        }

        return super.fitSystemWindows(insets);
    }
}
```

This is my fragment layout.

```
<com.dhna.widget.ZeroInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- your xml code -->

</ZeroInsetsFrameLayout>
```

I want it to be helpful to you.
good luck!

Comment: I almost got depression. I thought only I have issues with transparent status bar. And after 2 hours of searching. Finally got your answer. You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- After I had researched on all forum. thoese ways can not help find point out. Lucky when i tried doing this way. It helps me resolved problem

> XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
       <!-- Your xml -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView("Your Activity");
   setAdjustScreen();

}
```

> Created Func

```
protected void setAdjustScreen(){
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        /*android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"*/
}
```

> Finally adding some lines to your mainifest

```
 <activity
     android:name="Your Activity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

AndroidBug5497Workaround.java take care memory leak. need below code

```
getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
```

My sample using RxJava that automatically call removeOnGlobalLayoutListener() when onPause() in Activity's lifecycle

```
public class MyActivity extends RxAppCompatActivity {
    // ...

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

        TRSoftKeyboardVisibility
            .changes(this) // activity
            .compose(this.<TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent>bindUntilEvent(ActivityEvent.PAUSE))
            .subscribe(keyboardEvent -> {
                FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                View firstChildView = content.getChildAt(0);
                firstChildView.getLayoutParams().height = keyboardEvent.viewHeight();
                firstChildView.requestLayout();

                // keyboardEvent.isVisible      = keyboard visible or not
                // keyboardEvent.keyboardHeight = keyboard height
                // keyboardEvent.viewHeight     = fullWindowHeight - keyboardHeight
            });
   //...
}





package commonlib.rxjava.keyboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import kr.ohlab.android.util.Assert;
import rx.Observable;

public class TRSoftKeyboardVisibility {

    public static Observable<ChangeEvent> changes(Activity activity) {
        Assert.notNull(activity, "activity == null");
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View childOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
        return Observable.create(
            new TRSoftKeyboardVisibilityEventOnSubscribe(childOfContent));
    }

    public static final class ChangeEvent {
        private final int keyboardHeight;
        private final boolean visible;
        private final int viewHeight;

        public static ChangeEvent create(boolean visible, int keyboardHeight,
            int windowDisplayHeight) {
            return new ChangeEvent(visible, keyboardHeight, windowDisplayHeight);
        }

        private ChangeEvent(boolean visible, int keyboardHeight, int viewHeight) {
            this.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight;
            this.visible = visible;
            this.viewHeight = viewHeight;
        }

        public int keyboardHeight() {
            return keyboardHeight;
        }

        public boolean isVisible() {
            return this.visible;
        }

        public int viewHeight() {
            return viewHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof ChangeEvent)) return false;

            ChangeEvent that = (ChangeEvent) o;

            if (keyboardHeight != that.keyboardHeight) return false;
            if (visible != that.visible) return false;
            return viewHeight == that.viewHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = keyboardHeight;
            result = 31 * result + (visible ? 1 : 0);
            result = 31 * result + viewHeight;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ChangeEvent{" +
                "keyboardHeight=" + keyboardHeight +
                ", visible=" + visible +
                ", viewHeight=" + viewHeight +
                '}';
        }
    }
}


package commonlib.rxjava.keyboard;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import kr.ohlab.android.util.Assert;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.android.MainThreadSubscription;
import timber.log.Timber;

public class TRSoftKeyboardVisibilityEventOnSubscribe
    implements Observable.OnSubscribe<TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent> {
    private final View mTopView;
    private int mLastVisibleDecorViewHeight;
    private final Rect mWindowVisibleDisplayFrame = new Rect();

    public TRSoftKeyboardVisibilityEventOnSubscribe(View topView) {
        mTopView = topView;
    }

    private int computeWindowFrameHeight() {
        mTopView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(mWindowVisibleDisplayFrame);
        return (mWindowVisibleDisplayFrame.bottom - mWindowVisibleDisplayFrame.top);
    }

    private TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent checkKeyboardVisibility() {
        int windowFrameHeightNow = computeWindowFrameHeight();
        TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent event = null;
        if (windowFrameHeightNow != mLastVisibleDecorViewHeight) {
            int mTopViewHeight = mTopView.getHeight();
            int heightDiff = mTopViewHeight - windowFrameHeightNow;
            Timber.e("XXX heightDiff=" + heightDiff);
            if (heightDiff > (mTopViewHeight / 4)) {
                event = TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent.create(true, heightDiff, windowFrameHeightNow);
            } else {
                event = TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent.create(false, 0, windowFrameHeightNow);
            }
            mLastVisibleDecorViewHeight = windowFrameHeightNow;
            return event;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void call(final Subscriber<? super TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent> subscriber) {
        Assert.checkUiThread();

        final ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener =
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    TRSoftKeyboardVisibility.ChangeEvent event = checkKeyboardVisibility();
                    if( event == null)
                        return;
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onNext(event);
                    }
                }
            };

        mTopView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);

        subscriber.add(new MainThreadSubscription() {
            @Override
            protected void onUnsubscribe() {
                mTopView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have solved using coordinatorlayout

activity.main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:id="@+id/post_msg_recyclerview">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"


        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

now add this line  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

```
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        Adapter adapter1=new Adapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i use
in the main view in the xml file you will add this

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

then in the "onCreate" function you will before every thing get the status bar size like this

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0)
{
    status_bar=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
```

then finally in "onCreate" you will add this to update the size

```
        main_view= findViewById(R.id.the_main);
        main_view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
                view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                if (Math.abs(old_size - r.height()) > 100)
                {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = main_view.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = r.height()+ status_bar ;
                    main_view.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
                old_size = r.height();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't why but  option adjustResize doesn't work with fullscreen. I've just added titleBar and works (  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"). Insted that I use in code "  getSupportActionBar().hide();"

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
           />
```

Answer (score -1):

The best practice allows user scroll content when the keyboard is shown. 
So to add this functionality you need put your root layout inside the `ScrollView` and use `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` activity method.

But if you want to use this functionality with `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`
 flag on Android 5 content won't be scrollable and will overlaps with keyboard.

To solve this issue check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46490052/5439793)

Answer (score -1):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

      <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <Editext/>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView/>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```