# fitsSystemWindows prevents UI redraw

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to implement Translucent system bars and having some trouble with `fitsSystemWindows` preventing elements in the view from redrawing after they become hidden by an element like the keyboard.

As an example I have a submit button at the bottom of a form, if I start filling in the form the keyboard pops up, I enter data and then dismiss the keyboard and poof the submit button has gone.

I don't get this problem if I remove the `fitsSystemWindows` but then I have some major layout issues.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="PonyTheme" parent="@style/_PonyTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    //this is the only line that causes a problem
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Where is this theme being used? You probably don't want your Activity to have `fitsSystemWindows` set. Rather, you'd want to set that on the root View of the layout that you set as the content view in your Activity.

Comment: Yep I am using a custom theme that extends the holo.light theme. The custom theme is just some colouring from the http://android-holo-colors.com generator. I have `fitsSystemWindows` in the theme rather than the layout because I want to keep the action bar

Comment: You don't need that in the theme to be able to keep the ActionBar. Just remove `fitsSystemWindows` from `PonyTheme`, and apply it to your content view layout.

Comment: You're right. However, I still have the issue with the UI not redrawing

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more, but perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092888/windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-not-working-with-translucent-action-navbar/22266717#22266717) is related?

Comment: Ah, found the problem. The content that was not redrawing was in a `scrollView`. It would seem this does not play well with `fitsSystemWindows`. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out. :)