# Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar AdjustResize does not work

Tags: android, android-appcompat

So I am in the above situation: I am using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` so that I may use the new material design `Toolbar`. My XML structure is along the lines of:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/personalInfo_scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- textviews and various other form-related elements -->

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that no matter what I do `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` does not work. I have tried to assign weight to the `ScrollView` but to no effect.
Googling this issue turned up no results but it is my impression from what I have seen so far that adjustResize does not work with this theme?

As requested, here is the portion of the manifest with the relevant activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Information"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_information"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.Account"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by `adjustResize`? Because I haven't got this question. Can you describe the question more? also give your complete layout xml and your android manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Put this property in your root LinearLayout

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Source: 
pablisco -
[windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working with translucent action/navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092888/windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-not-working-with-translucent-action-navbar)