# Softkeyboard overlaps EditText

Tags: android

My root layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

content FrameLayout being replaced with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:text="@string/no_messages"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>

        <af.kabuljan.android.ui.widget.EmptyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/md_indigo_100"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnAttach"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment"
            android:tint="@color/primary_dark"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:hint="@string/enterMessage"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAttach"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Let's assume this is a messaging app and this window has a recyclerView with bubble messages which can be scrolled, but bottom input should be always at bottom. The problem is when i tap EditText - softkeyboard always overlaps this EditText. What should i do to make whole container (toolbar+recyclerView+bottom input) be resized to lay out softkeyboard to the bottom?

Tried `adjustResize` - no result.
I've attached 2 screenshots. 1st - wrong, 2nd - correct.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you were on the right track with the `adjustResize`, that's what you should do to specify the desired activity layout behaviour wwith the soft keyboard.

What setting did you try, and did it have any affect?

The docs are here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: tried adjustResize - no effect at all, adjustPan moving all content uppper and that way Toolbar is no longer visible, EditText however is visible.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest with the `adjustResize` setting?

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".ui.messages.MessagesActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

Comment: Hmm... can you try adding the `android:fitSystemWindows` setting (as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21860837/1715829))?