# Android Keyboard Adjust Resize

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am Developing one Application which contains Activity and `Fragment`. In Fragment Layout I used Relative Layout as Parent Layout,one button in bottom and in between Scrollview. `Scrollview` contains editText Boxes. If i click Last `editTextBox` in scrollview My keyboard hides the `fragment`. I tried `adjustpan|adjustresize` in manifest and also in my `fragment` but not yet problem resolved.

Comment: have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34563274/2826147)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Android's bugs in this. After struggling a lot, I am able to come-up with a smooth workaround to this problem. it is a one line solution, but it has some pre-reqs. The one line is:

```
AndroidBug5497Workaround.assistActivity(this, R.id.LayoutInScrollView);
```

Your xml Layout must be like:

```
RelativeLayout{

 HeaderView{}

 ScrollView{
  LinearLayout{ 
    @+id/LayoutInScrollView
  }
 }

 FooterView{}      // the buttons u want to appear above keyboard
}
```

If you are not using Full Screen, the following class should be enough:

```
class AndroidBug5497Workaround{

    View svChildLayout;
    int originalGravity;
    Activity activity;

    /**
     * @param activity
     * @param svChildLayoutId  id of the layout that is the first child of the center ScrollView
     */
    public static void assistActivity (Activity activity, int svChildLayoutId) {
        new AndroidBug5497Workaround(activity, svChildLayoutId);
    }


    private AndroidBug5497Workaround(Activity activity, int svChildLayoutId) {

        this.activity = activity;
        svChildLayout = activity.findViewById(svChildLayoutId);
        originalGravity = ((ScrollView.LayoutParams)svChildLayout.getLayoutParams()).gravity;

        //Add listener
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
        mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                possiblyResizeChildOfContent2();
            }
        });

    }
    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent2() {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
            if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4)) {
                // keyboard probably just became visible
                onKeyboardVisible();
            } else {
                // keyboard probably just became hidden
                onKeyboardHidden();
            }
            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }


    private void onKeyboardVisible() {

        ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) svChildLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        svChildLayout.requestLayout();

        final ScrollView parentSv = (ScrollView) svChildLayout.getParent();
        parentSv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View focusedEditText = activity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
                parentSv.smoothScrollTo(0, focusedEditText.getTop() );
            }
        });
    }

    private void onKeyboardHidden() {
        ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) svChildLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = originalGravity;
        svChildLayout.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

---

If you are using full screen, you'll need the following class (modified from [windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working with translucent action/navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092888/windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-not-working-with-translucent-action-navbar) ):

```
    public class AndroidBug5497Workaround {

        // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
        // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

        public static void assistActivity (Activity activity, int svChildLayoutId) {
            new AndroidBug5497Workaround(activity, svChildLayoutId);
        }

        private View mChildOfContent;
        private int usableHeightPrevious;
        private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

        View svChildLayout;
        int originalGravity;
        Activity activity;

        private AndroidBug5497Workaround(Activity activity, int svChildLayoutId) {


        this.activity = activity;
        svChildLayout = activity.findViewById(svChildLayoutId);
        originalGravity = ((ScrollView.LayoutParams)svChildLayout.getLayoutParams()).gravity;

            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
            mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
                }
            });
            frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
        }

        private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent() {
            int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
            if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
                int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
                int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
                if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4)) {
                    // keyboard probably just became visible
onKeyboardVisible();                    
frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;
                } else {
                    // keyboard probably just became hidden
onKeyboardHidden();                    
frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
                }
                mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
                usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
            }
        }

        private int computeUsableHeight() {


               Rect r = new Rect();
                mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                return (r.bottom - r.top);
            }

private void onKeyboardVisible() {

        ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) svChildLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        svChildLayout.requestLayout();

        final ScrollView parentSv = (ScrollView) svChildLayout.getParent();
        parentSv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View focusedEditText = activity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
                parentSv.smoothScrollTo(0, focusedEditText.getTop() );
            }
        });
    }

    private void onKeyboardHidden() {
        ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) svChildLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = originalGravity;
        svChildLayout.requestLayout();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: @usman nice solution. i face similar problem i tried to use similar workaround but it is not working. i have also tried to use you custom workaround for none fullscreen activity but it did not work. also i tried the full screen version and it created an extra white space above keyboard. I have posted my issue with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328468/scrolling-in-scrollview-inside-a-fragment-in-viewpager-with-soft-keyboard-visibl) i would appreciate your help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in **AndroidMenifest**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize
```

In your **editext** use this

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```