# Activity isn't resizing when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I have a simple activity that displays a big multiline `EditText` and some other controls below it. I want the activity to resize so the buttons are not hidden by the keyboard when the user is typing in the `EditText`.

I have tried all sorts of sketchy and non-sketchy solutions I have found online - nothing works.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest.
- Putting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the layout root.
- Using `RelativeLayout` vs. `LinearLayout` as root.
- Removed all themes from the activity
- Created a custom theme and put `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` in it.
- Tried the proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34563082/930640), with my entire activity layout inside a `ScrollView`.

Anything left to try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the following lines in your `onCreate()`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Then your Activity will automatically push up/down when , Key Board shown/hide in screen.

Setting up with , Manifest file , didn't work for me.

Comment: +1000 Thanks! Can't believe something this simple (and that actually works!) hasn't been mentioned in any of the other threads I've looked at regarding this question... They all come up with extremely convoluted and sketchy solutions - ScrollView's , entire classes that only "solve" this problem (without solving it), etc, etc.

Comment: @BadCash glad to hear from you.:)

Comment: +1000 thanks!!! For some reasons setting this parameter in the XML doesn't leads the to the same result. THANKYOU.

Answer (score -1):

Put your form inside `ScrollView`. So that when keyboard pop-out, your components are able to scroll.