# Android soft keyboard not pushing up views that are reselected

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-input-method, android-textinputedittext

So, I have a `EditText` and I have a function that is hiding keyboard when you click outside `EditText`. What happens is next:

1. First time `EditText` is selected, keyboard comes up and it pushes whole `View` up.
2. I deselect `EditText` (click anywheere otuside of `EditText`) and keyboard goes to hidden
3. When I click again on `EditText`, keyboard comes up, but `View` isn't pulled up and I cannot see my `EditText`

How to push that View up again when `EditText` is selected?

Here is code for hiding SoftKeyboard:

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    View v = getCurrentFocus();

    if (v != null &&
            (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) &&
            v instanceof EditText &&
            !v.getClass().getName().startsWith("android.webkit.")) {
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = ev.getRawX() + v.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = ev.getRawY() + v.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (x < v.getLeft() || x > v.getRight() || y < v.getTop() || y > v.getBottom())
            hideKeyboard(this);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

and `hideKeyboard()` method

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null && activity.getWindow().getDecorView() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try use the built-in methods .Here is the solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042489/activity-isnt-resizing-when-keyboard-is-shown/43042545#43042545

Comment: Already tried adjust_resize and the rest from that bundle..

Comment: Have you tried these http://stackoverflow.com/a/23381583/4239410

Comment: Yeah, tried everything from built in methods for the activity in manifest and in onCreate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution...

I had to use dummy layout(in my case `LinearLayout`):

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null && activity.getWindow().getDecorView() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }    
activity.findViewById(R.id.dummy).requestFocus();    
}
```

Now, when I reselect my EditText, its working.

Answer (score 2):

use this method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @Miljan It's worked, i have checked.can you try this.

Comment: EditText EditHello= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_hello);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(EditHello, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);