# windowSoftInputMode hides Textfield

Tags: android, html, css, keyboard

So I had this problem where when the Soft Keyboard comes up it shrinks my background image to adjust the screen size. Many had suggested to change

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

This worked for the background. But the problem is it's breaking functionality elsewhere.

I have a textbox thats fixed to the bottom of the screen. With `adjustResize` when the user taps on this textbox it fixes itself to the keyboard. But after changing to `adjustPan` the textbox is getting covered by the keyboard. How do I fix both my problems?

- Not have the background shrink when the keyboard appears.
- Fix a textbox positioned to the bottom to the keyboard when it
  appears.

[image]

EDIT: I'am using the latest version of Ionic 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042489/activity-isnt-resizing-when-keyboard-is-shown/43042545#43042545

Comment: Can you enclose the layout fields in a scroll view and set background for the scroll view.