# layout is not able to resize even after setting windowsSoftInputMode and using scrollview

Tags: android

My code is as below:

activity_payment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_base" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Credit card"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFuscousGray"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cardName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textCard"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:hint="Name on card"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilverChaliceac"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cardNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:hint="Credit card number xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="19"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilverChaliceac"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expiryLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardNumber"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/expiry"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                    android:hint="Expiry MM/YY"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilverChaliceac"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="34dp"
                        android:layout_height="21dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_card" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cvv"
                        android:layout_width="93dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:hint="CVV"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSilverChaliceac"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />

                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/expiryLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                    android:text="Save this card"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFuscousGray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/payLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorRoyalPurple">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/payButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Pay"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_titlebar">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backArrow"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backArrow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.PaymentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" />
```

Even after I set all the things, when soft keyboard goes up,it is not able to push the layout upward. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: add some extra padding to bottom of your layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042489/activity-isnt-resizing-when-keyboard-is-shown/43042545#43042545

Answer (score 0):

Remove "adjustPan"

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: I have put fitSystemWindows = "true". Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

> "adjustResize"
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.
>
> "adjustPan"
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Use adjustResize instead of adjustPan to get your desired effect.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```