# How to implement this view

Tags: android, android-layout

I meet a view
`MobilePlayerActivity`(from China douyutv app)
set with

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

But in picture:[image]
[image]

We can see that the `EditText` don't popup the `contentView`.

So My question is **why the contentView can not been popped up** and how to implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042489/activity-isnt-resizing-when-keyboard-is-shown/43042545#43042545

Answer (score 0):

Just set like `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` is not enough, `Activity` also needs! (From Chinese employee)