# React native android fitSystemWindows does not take effect

Tags: android, css, layout, keyboard, react-native

Is there any alternative to fitSystemWindows() in react-native for android?

My use case is following : I use translucent status bar flag to draw under the status bar, in which case KEYBOARD RESIZE doesn't work (standard android limitaion) the solution of which is to apply window insets - which is whenever system windows insets using fitsystemwindows=true are received the respective views set the same amount of padding around .

Here is a reference: [windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working with translucent action/navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092888/windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-not-working-with-translucent-action-navbar)

But since react-native controls the layout system, I see that the fitsystemwindows is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) solves the keyboard resize issue when using edge-to-edge view.