# push button above keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an EditText and a button and some other TextViews in a fragment layout.The parent of the layout is Constraint Layout and the activity that holds it is a Relative layout. When the layout is displayed the keyboard is displayed but I want the button to be pushed above the keyboard.I gave the the attribute **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** to the manifest file in the activity that holds the fragment layout.Still did not help me!!I have referred to one of the following links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751094/android-button-above-keyboard), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard), bu the answers did not help me...

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Otp.Otp"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/otp_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/masked_splash">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/intro_logo_wdth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/intro_logo_hght"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/msked_splsh_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/otp_lyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msked_splsh_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:**
In the above layout **@+id/otp_lyt** is the id where fragment is fragment is loaded.

Fragment_Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ph_verify_lbl_mrgn"
        android:text="@string/verify_your_phone_number"
        android:textColor="#bb2b67"

        android:textSize="@dimen/ph_verify_head_tsxtsze"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_lorem_ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/head" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phnmbr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_txt_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/ph_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="@dimen/ph_verify_head_tsxtsze"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/next"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/next"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.909"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/next"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/next"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Screenshot1:

[image]

Screenshot2:

[image]

TEST:
Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
```

Comment: add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: Nope ..It is still the same bro

Comment: Remove app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" from your button widget in fragment layout and then check.

Comment: @AIK That wasnt the issue

Comment: Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root layout

Comment: Which root?Activity or fragment?

Comment: I added it to the root of fragment.Not working still...

Comment: try this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" or put this in your fragment's onCreateView getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: Tried both...But that didnot work

Comment: the relativelayout in your main layout file is not recommended to play the role of Fragment Container due to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui. Should it work if we change the container from RelativeLayout to FrameLayout ?

Comment: I suggest you change your constraint layout to relative layout in fragment.

Comment: I used constraint because there are 6 ediitexts which are to be aligned perfectly next to each other.I could do that by chaining them n Constraint  Layout.Dont know how to do it in Relativelayout

Comment: Nope Framelayout does not help either..

Comment: In Relative layout I have to set margins for those edittexts for each screen falling under certain dp. In constraint I dont have to worry about that

Comment: first try with only one edittext if that doesn't work you can go with constraint layout. The point is to check whether the button pushes up when keyboard opens.

Comment: Trying it..........

Comment: Even that it isnt helping with Relative

Comment: Can you post your activity.java and fragment.java and manifest file?

Comment: I tried it with a different prjct.Will post now

Comment: posted..plz check it

Comment: @jobin Hi, I have same problem , did you find the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your acitivty is fullscreen. If it's true `"adjustResize"` will not be working. See [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)