# Soft Keyboard is hiding edit text behind it

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-input-method

I have set activity with SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN in onCreate() method as below

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`
```

[Screenshot Link: Note that soft keyboard is covering the edit text behind it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slvx8.png)

It works fine when used adjustResize instead of adjustPan.

Comment: then use `adjustResize`

Comment: @NikunjParadva, adjust resize dont hide the action bar. I want action bar hidden when keyboard opens.

Comment: give `marginBottom` to edittext then..

Comment: @sanjeev.. tried giving margin bottom but it is not effecting anything. It seems , adjustpan makes soft keaboard stick to edittext bottom.

Comment: Please refer detailed discussion on Keyboard hiding [AdjustResize vs fitsSystemWindows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860837/3787344)