# Android: Keyboard hiding EditText in Fragment [Material]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan, adjust-android

**Premise:** I have a fragment located within a *frame layout* in the activity layout. ***The application is in full screen mode***.

[image: How fragment looks like]

**Problem:** When the keyboard lifts up, it hides some edit text, *even the one that currently has the focus*.

[image: Problem]

**Actions already taken:** I have already tried setting the flags in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  
// OR
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
// OR ...
```

but nothing worked. I also tried setting the flag in the fragment's onCreateView (I also tried in onCreate), but without success.

```
...
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
...
```

**Question:** What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092888/windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-not-working-with-translucent-action-navbar and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Comment: @Rainmaker thanks for the reply but i've but I also tried these things. The end result was that everything behind the fragment is resized but the views of the fragment do not.

Comment: do you try to put fragment in scrollview

Comment: @ahmedshaaban Yes, I tried but nothing or better to say it's not the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem: i was using `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02` apparently it seems to have problems with the auto-adjustment of the screen. 
Changing with `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06` it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scrollview for parent to your form.